# Unhide "Item is a Record" column SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

"**Item is a Record**" column is not showing under site columns. We are able to see this column into view also able to add this column into "**All Documents**" view but unable to use value of this column.

[image: All Document View]

[image: Site Columns]

Answer (score 2):

It is by designer that "item is a Record" column is not showing under site columns.

For more inforamtion about “Item is a Record” column, refer to the following articles.

Modern vs Classic IN PLACE Records Management in SharePoint for your reference:

https://regarding365.com/modern-vs-classic-in-place-records-management-in-sharepoint-8424ebab29f1

Overview of retention labels:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/labels